# Nullable DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, variable-assignment, nullable

I have two questions related to DateTime assingments

```
DateTime? y = 1 == 1 ? null: DateTime.MaxValue;
DateTime? y = null; // assignment works as expected
```

- Why the first assignment issues error of type conversion between `null` and `DateTime?`
- Which is the preferred way for null assignments of `DateTime?` in c#.

  ```
  DateTime? x = default(DateTime?); //prints null on console

  DateTime? x = null;               // prints null on console

  DateTime? x = DateTime.MinValue;  //print 01/01/0001
  ```

Comment: You need to cast `DateTime.MaxValue` to `(DateTime?)` or cast the null. There's no conversion between `DateTime` and `null`, since `DateTime` is non-nullable.

Comment: default(), for any value type (DateTime is a value type) will always call the parameterless constructor. The parameterless constructor in this case, does not have a value to assign, thus you are seeing the null in console

Answer (score 6):

The second statement `DateTime? y = null;` is only an assignment of null to a nullable object.

Whereas the first is a conditional assignment, which assigns some value for the true state and some other value for the false; Here you are using the conditional operator for evaluating the condition. according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ty67wk28.aspx) **first_expression** *(executes if true)* and **second_expression***(executes if false)* must be of same type or an implicit conversion must exist from one type to the other. In our case both are different so The simple solution is  doing an explicit conversion as like this:

```
DateTime? y = 1 == 1 ?(DateTime?) null : DateTime.MaxValue;
```

Comment: I think best option will be to typecast `DateTime.MaxValue` instead of `null`. That way it will make more sense and easily understood by OP and others.

Answer (score 3):

**A1.** Because in [ternary operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ty67wk28.aspx) both expressions/results should be of same type.

Acc. to MSDN `Either the type of first_expression and second_expression must be the same, or an implicit conversion must exist from one type to the other.`

In your question, `null` and `DateTime.MinValue` do not match and hence the error `conversion between null and DateTime`.

You can do

```
DateTime? y = 1 == 1 ? null : (DateTime?)DateTime.MaxValue;
```

This way both answers return an answer whose type is `DateTime?`.

**A2.** Normally there is no said/preferred way of assigning this. This depends on user convention. All three are good and depend on user requirements.

Comment: Because they *why* is more important than the fix.

Answer (score 2):

Because [?: Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ty67wk28.aspx) operator expects same type on both sides.

Either the type of first_expression and second_expression must be the same, or an implicit conversion must exist from one type to the other.

So solution will be like below:

```
DateTime? y = 1 == 1 ? (DateTime?)null : DateTime.MaxValue;
```

And for second question, this will be good way for null assignment

```
DateTime? x = null;
```

Answer (score 2):

> DateTime? y = 1 == 1 ? null: DateTime.MaxValue;

This statement is giving an assignment error not because of the null assignment to a variable it is because of using null assignment in ternary operator and as you are using a class type here you the ternary operator do not lead you to do this illegal stuff as per CLR specifications mentioned,It might give you a straight compilation error.

```
//Which is the preferred way for null assignments of DateTime? in c#.

DateTime? x = default(DateTime?); //prints null on console

DateTime? x = null; // prints null on console

DateTime? x = DateTime.MinValue; //print 01/01/0001
```

As per Specifications and guidelines provided the Class Types should not be assigned null in any scenario so as per standard you can use the min value(though you can use default value too but it might effect in type conversions when needed)

Answer (score 1):

The second one that you mentioned. You need to cast null value in this time asmensioned by Sir Nikhil Agrawal.

> Ternary

```
  int y = 1;
  DateTime? dt3 = y == 1 ? (DateTime?)null : DateTime.MinValue;
```

> Traditional way

```
       DateTime? dt3 = null;

        if (y == 1)            
             dt3 = null;            
        else
            dt3 = DateTime.MinValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to cast null to nullable datetime then you can use

```
DateTime? dt = (DateTime?)null;
```