# how to insert to database 00/00/0000 in datetime column when datetime picker checkbox not checked C# and SQL SERVER?

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I would like to be able to insert to database 00/00/0000 or any other value except today's date value for datetimepicker if checkbox property not checked , I tried more than one solution from this site but its always inserting the datetime value for today even if checkbox not checked .

This is the save button code :

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            if (dateOpened.Checked==true)
            {
                dateOpened.Enabled = true;
                dateOpened.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
             
            }
            else
            {
                dateOpened.Enabled = false;
                dateOpened.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
                dateOpened.CustomFormat = "00/00/0000";
            }

            if (dateFinished.Checked== true)
            {
                dateFinished.Enabled = true;
                dateFinished.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
            }
            else
            {
                dateFinished.Enabled = false;
                dateFinished.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
                dateFinished.CustomFormat = "00/00/0000";
            }

            if (add==1)
            {
                test.ADD_INVENTORIES(Convert.ToInt32(comboTest.SelectedValue),txtLotNo.Text,
                                     Convert.ToInt32(txtNoOfTests.Text),
                                     DateTime.Parse(dateReceived.Value.ToString()),
                                     DateTime.Parse(dateExpiry.Value.ToString()),
                                     DateTime.Parse(dateOpened.Value.ToString()),
                                     txtReceivedfrom.Text,
                                     DateTime.Parse(dateFinished.Value.ToString()),
                                     
                                     Convert.ToInt32(comboDepts.SelectedValue),
                                     Convert.ToInt32(txtRemaning.Text),
                                     Convert.ToInt32(comboCompany.SelectedValue),
                                     Convert.ToInt32(comboType.SelectedValue));

                MessageBox.Show("Stock Added Successfully", "New Stock", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                cleardata();
            }
}
```

This is the stored procedure code :

```
CREATE proc [dbo].[ADD_INVENTORIES]
@testid int,
@lot_no nvarchar(20),
@No_Of_Tests int,
@Received_Date datetime,
@Expiry_Date datetime,
@Opened_Date datetime,
@Received_From nvarchar(50),
@Finished_Date datetime,
@deptid int,
@Remaining_Tests int,
@Company_id int,
@reagent_type int



as 
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Inventory_Details]
           ([testid]
           ,[lot_no]
           ,[No_Of_Tests]
           ,[Received_Date]
           ,[Expiry_Date]
           ,[Opened_Date]
           ,[Received_From]
           ,[Finished_Date]
           ,[deptid]
           ,[Remaining_Tests]
           ,[Company_id]
           ,[reagent_type])
     VALUES
           (@testid
           ,@lot_no
           ,@No_Of_Tests
           ,@Received_Date
           ,@Expiry_Date
           ,@Opened_Date
           ,@Received_From
           ,@Finished_Date
           ,@deptid
           ,@Remaining_Tests
           ,@Company_id
           ,@reagent_type)
```

I want to insert to database 00/00/0000 for datetime columns (Opened_Date and Finished_Date) if checkbox not checked for datetimepicker. But its inserting the date and time for today's , I dont know where is the missing maybe I need to change the insert way and this way not correct :

```
DateTime.Parse(dateOpened.Value.ToString()),
DateTime.Parse(dateFinished.Value.ToString()),
```

How to solve this issue ?

Comment: This is not so easy, C# doesn't understand Datetime null, for that you need Datetime? or Datetime2, or Nullable Datetime, neither classes of Datetime. I suggest you search here, there is a lot of information about nullable datetime in c# with database

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nullable DateTime in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36300160/nullable-datetime-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @Leandro I will check it if it solve my issue I will till you thank you

Comment: No problem, maybe you can put more information or tries in order to be more specific with the answer.

Comment: @Leandro I changed the question to be more specific. :) , I confused about it , if I cannot find the solution I will remove these 2 columns from insert and I will create another procedure to update the date value when needed, but I don't need it in insert at the first time.

Comment: Your SQL code looks like T-SQL - which means you're either using SQL Server or Sybase. Now I've never worked with Sybase but in SQL Server, `00/00/0000` is not a valid value for any of the date / datetime data types.

Comment: DateTimePicker doesn't accept either null DateTime or an illegal DateTime. It does accept DateTime.MinValue, of course. If you need to handle null DateTime values, you need to build a Custom Control and handle those dates *manually*. What to show in the DTP is something else... If it's bound, probably just handle the `Parse` and `Format` events of the Binding

Comment: I use 2099 as null year, in any case ill be dead when that system brokes if there any pc that can run it:D

Comment: @Leandro The rate medical science is advancing, 2099 might not be far enough in the future. I just use null, or [2525](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1FgSmdfRUus) if I really have to.

Comment: I hope im not working at 2099 anymore, or supporting a 80yo app. Trying to be real. In any case you can't use null with a Datetime, you need to use a nullable Datatime or Datetime2

Comment: @Leandro I just wanted to link to a song I like... Anyway DateTime2 is an SQL data type, not a c# data type. Personally, I would go with c# nullable DateTime and SQL DateTime2 in cases I don't need time zone support, and nullable DateTimeOffset in cases I do need time zone support.

Comment: @ZoharPeled that's a +1 answer for this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the way to deal with this case , I removed the columns Opened_Date and Finished_Date from insert statement because I dont use it first , I need to fill these dates later on when use these products that time I will create update stored procedure to update the open date when use the products and enter finish date when products finished.

```
CREATE proc [dbo].[ADD_INVENTORIES]
@testid int,
@lot_no nvarchar(20),
@No_Of_Tests int,
@Received_Date datetime,
@Expiry_Date datetime,
@Received_From nvarchar(50),
@deptid int,
@Remaining_Tests int,
@Company_id int,
@reagent_type int



as 
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Inventory_Details]
           ([testid]
           ,[lot_no]
           ,[No_Of_Tests]
           ,[Received_Date]
           ,[Expiry_Date]
           ,[Received_From]
           ,[deptid]
           ,[Remaining_Tests]
           ,[Company_id]
           ,[reagent_type])
     VALUES
           (@testid
           ,@lot_no
           ,@No_Of_Tests
           ,@Received_Date
           ,@Expiry_Date
           ,@Received_From
           ,@deptid
           ,@Remaining_Tests
           ,@Company_id
           ,@reagent_type)
```